# What's the difference between Github and Putty SSH key placement configurations?

Tags: windows, git, ssh, putty

The [github instructions](http://help.github.com/win-set-up-git/) say to setup your SSH keys in `~/.ssh` using the windows git bash program.

I have in the past used Putty to manage ssh keys.

What is the difference between the 2 setups?

This is for my own git server.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a pretty old question, but here's the answer:

Basically, PuTTY stores all its sessions in the Windows registry, rather than in a config file in a home folder, whereas the default git+ssh setup uses openSSH and it's style of key configuration (files that are typically stored in `~/.ssh`, i.e., `/home/<username>/.ssh`).

In Windows, if you'd rather use PuTTY than openSSH, set an environment variable named GIT_SSH to  `C:\your\putty\folder\plink.exe`. Then, you can reference any saved session in PuTTY by using a remote url of the form `ssh://<session name>/<repository path>`. This allows you to, for example, specify particular keys with each session, similarly to how you could use `~/.ssh/config` to specify a particular key with the `IdentityFile` option.

Answer (score 0):

Git uses an SSH program to deal with SSH accesses, basically the default one depending on your system (look at the `GIT_SSH` environment variable). So it's just to ease the configuration that they say to setup SSH keys in `~/.ssh`. If you want to put SSH keys in another directory, just tell it by using `ssh-add /path/to/your/key`.